# How to add policyset in separate json file in sitecore commerce 8.2.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have a Sitecore commerce 8.2.1 engine, and using the default habitat environment files:

- PlugIn.Habitat.CommerceAuthoring-1.0.0.json
- PlugIn.Habitat.CommerceMinions-1.0.0.json
- PlugIn.Habitat.CommerceShops-1.0.0.json

For a custom plugin, we would like to separate the Policy settings in a separate json file. For example:  Plugin.CustomPluginName.PolicySet-1.0.0.json

Contains:

```
{
    "$type":  "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.PolicySet, Sitecore.Commerce.Core",
    "Id":  "Entity-PolicySet-CustomPluginNamePolicySet",
    "Version":  1,
    "IsPersisted":  false,
    "Name":  "CustomPluginNamePolicySet",
    "Policies":  {
             "$type":  "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Policy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core]], mscorlib",
             "$values":  [
                             {
                                 "$type":  "Plugin.CustomPluginName.CustomPluginNameClientPolicy, Plugin.CustomPluginName",
                                 ...
                             }
                         ]
     }
}
```

I've added a reference to it in the habitat environment files:

```
{
    "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.PolicySetPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core",
    "PolicySetId": "Entity-PolicySet-CustomPluginNamePolicySet"
},
```

When bootstrapping, I get the following error:

> InvalidEnvironmentJson
>
> Environment json is not valid.

Is it possible to do this in Sitecore 8.2.1? And how?

I've seen an example for this in Sitecore 9 (Braintree plugin), but I can't find an example for 8.2.1

Comment: No, it’s impossible to do that in 8.2.1